# Setting /usr/bin/gcc and /usr/bin/g++ on SLES 15 when using gcc-12 package

Tags: opensuse, sles, gcc

I'm trying to consume GCC 12.3 in SLES when using the packaged `gcc-12` installed with `zypper`.

The compiler works and it's available on `/usr/bin/gcc-12` alongside with `/usr/bin/g++-12`, but I don't have a link to `/usr/bin/gcc` nor `/usr/bin/g++` and I need them to avoid breaking with some packages that look specifically for those binaries.

How is the right way to achieve this on SLES? In the RHEL world there's the `scl` scripts with `gcc-toolset-12` to proper set the paths on the system.